# MySQL Must Match both columns in 2 tables... otherwise return empty result?

Tags: php, mysql, database, join

I have an SQL query like so:

```
SELECT t1.key, t1.value
FROM table1 AS t1, table2 AS t2
WHERE t1.pID IN (45, 67, 88, 32) AND t2.id = t1.id;
```

This seems to return all rows where `t1.pId IN (45, 67, 88, 32)`, but it shouldn't since t2.id should reduce the row results even further, but doesn't seem like it is doing this.

I need to reduce the rows returned via the t2.id, but if t2.id is not found after sorting through the t1.pId values array, it should return an empty result.

***EDITED***
Table, trying to select `t1` columns, not `t2`, sorry.  But only if both conditions are met, and only return the resulting rows after the 2nd condition is true. Also, fixed the table now so it is correct.

Comment: what if you join data on a common key between 2 tables ?

Comment: There is no common key between the 2... sorry

Comment: `t2.id = t1.pID` implies that that's the common key between the two tables.

Comment: Yeah, but it needs to sort by the array in the first WHERE statement first, and than check if `t2.id = t1.pID` after..., if not found, than should return empty result.

Comment: There is no "sort by the array" operation; use an ORDER BY clause to specify the order for the return. If any row satisfies the predicates, the row will be returned. An "empty set" will be returned only if there are zero rows that satisfy the predicates. The predicates are evaluated on each individual row.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is returning each row that meets the specified criteria. That is, it's checking only if an individual row satisfies the predicates, and returns the rows that do, irregardless of any rows that don't.

If I understand what you're asking (and I'm not entirely sure I do), you say you want to return an "empty set" when some rows satisfy the predicate on t1.id but there's at least one row in t1 that doesn't have a matching row in t2.

To check if any rows don't have a "match" in t2, we can use an anti-join pattern (there's other approaches as well...

```
SELECT SUM(1) AS t1_rows_not_matched
  FROM table1 t1
  LEFT
  JOIN table2 t2
    ON t2.id = t1.id
 WHERE t1.pID IN (45, 67, 88, 32)
   AND t2.id IS NULL
```

Go get that incorporated into your query, you could use that as an inline view, and include a predicate to check the number of rows that aren't matched, for example:

```
SELECT d.key
     , d.value
  FROM ( SELECT SUM(1) AS cnt_rows_not_matched
           FROM table1 t1
           LEFT
           JOIN table2 t2
             ON t2.id = t1.id
          WHERE t1.pID IN (45, 67, 88, 32)
            AND t2.id IS NULL
       ) c
 CROSS
  JOIN table1 d
 WHERE d.pID IN (45, 67, 88, 32)
   AND c.cnt_rows_not_matched = 0
```

This may not answer the question you were asking, but it's not clear exactly what you were asking.

---

Each row is checked individually. If a satisfies the predicates, it will be returned. The query you posted will return an empty set only if there are NO rows that match.

It's possible that you are wanting to check that there is at least one row that matches each of the `pID` values included in the list. That is, for example, if there is no row that has a pID value of `32`, then you want the query to return an empty set, rather than the set of rows that do meet the criteria.

```
SELECT d.key
     , d.value
  FROM ( SELECT SUM(1) AS cnt_rows_not_matched
           FROM table1 t1
           LEFT
           JOIN table2 t2
             ON t2.id = t1.id
          WHERE t1.pID IN (45, 67, 88, 32)
            AND t2.id IS NULL
       ) c
 CROSS
  JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT f.pID) AS cnt_pid
           FROM table1 f
          WHERE f.pID IN (45, 67, 88, 32)
       ) p
 CROSS
  JOIN table1 d
 WHERE d.pID IN (45, 67, 88, 32)
   AND c.cnt_rows_not_matched = 0
   AND p.cnt_pid = 4
```

---

Comment: I want to return all rows that meet both `WHERE` statements.  Otherwise, do not return them and, instead, return an empty result.  Does that help to make it clearer?  And thanks btw.

Comment: Thanks again, but I don't think you follow me here.  I just want to return rows where both `WHERE` clauses are true... like I would normally do an `INNER JOIN` on table2 that should get rid of the left table values if the `table2` `ON` statement was not true.  This is exactly what I want to do, but don't think that `INNER JOIN` will work here... unless I'm wrong?

Comment: There is only one WHERE clause in the statement, not two. There are two _predicates_ in the WHERE clause. The boolean AND operator specifies that a row must satisfy _both_ predicates in order for it to be returned. That's what your original statement does. With an inner join, it doesn't matter whether the predicate appears in the `WHERE` clause or the `ON` clause. (The old school comma join operator, as in your query, is a JOIN operation. Absent example data, and desired result (and how that differs from the output from the query you posted, I can't help you.

Comment: @Solomon Closson: your query does an INNER JOIN operation. Your query uses old-school comma operator syntax for the join operation, but it's still an INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the comma-syntax to join the tables is causing MySQL to do something you're not expecting, but if you rewrote it to use an explicit JOIN, then I think you will find it clearer where your conditions are and how the JOIN is happening. Here's a suggestion:

```
SELECT t2.key, t2.value
FROM table1 AS t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.id IN (45, 67, 88, 32)
      AND t2.id IS NOT NULL
```

The idea here is that you are explicitly joining the table t2, and declaring how it should be joined.

Then, you reduce the rows to only those that were joined successfully by eliminating all rows with a NULL in `t2.id`. `t2.id` will be null if there was no matching t2 row, when joining on `t1.id = t2.id`

Comment: Updated question, sorry about that, was not entirely correct... please have a look.  Thanks :)

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your edit, but it looks like you just changed some column names and/or want to select different columns. I updated my SQL to reflect the changes I noticed, but it was just a matter of changing the column names. The same technique should still work.